# Add dollar sign to editText when field is clicked android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I would like to add a dollar sign ($) automatically when the *editText* field is clicked. I've attempted to use **addTextChangedListener** but it doesn't work as expected.
I do not want to add it after the use has finishes entering all the text. Just want it to be added once the field is clicked or becomes the focus.

```
EditText editTextAd;

editTextAd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                editTextAd.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                            keyDel = true;
                        }else{
                            keyDel = false;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if (!keyDel) {
                    String str = s.toString();
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        str += "$";
                        editTextAd.setText(str);
                        editTextAd.setSelection(str.length());
                        //keyDel=false;
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOnKeyListener` is listening keys from Keyboard(hardware).

Change EditText.text in `onTextChanged` will cause a never-end loop which actually won't work.

> when the editText field is clicked

The event is according to `setOnClickListener` or `setOnTouchListener`.

> becomes the focus

The event is `setOnFocusChangeListener`.

Comment: thanks for your help. Did the setOnFocusChangeListener with an append and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Step - 1:** First call edittext.setOnfocusChangeListner so that on user click on your editText it detect its focus.

**Step - 2:** Call edittext.setText("$"); which set $ sign in first position on editText.

**Step - 3:** Call editText.setSelection(1) so that your cursor will start at position 1 not 0.

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus){
                    editText.setText("$");
                    editText.setSelection(1);
                }
            }
        });
```